# Как в Python создать свой ПО фреймворк?

Tags: python, python-3.x

хочу в основном ради обучения, ну и не только, попробовать написать свой ПО фреймворк на Python. Но вот сколько гуглю только нашел информацию по ВЕБ-фреймворкам, но никак не по ПО. Подскажите способы. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Что он должен уметь, зачем он нужен? Самописные фреймворки не появляются просто так, они рождаются на базе существующей кодовой базы, при известном пуле часто возникающих задач.

Comment: на питоне будет не эффективно и медленно, пишите на си или асм.

Comment: @Интик Нормально будет, не надо тут вашего asm.

Comment: @Victor VosMottor               по фреймворк работающий с 1 ядром это не нормально

Comment: Я думаю что если уметь оптимизировать, + учесть скорость многих пк, то не будет медленно, а си, ну как бы нет, есть С++, который гораздо круче, но я его не знаю, и учить врятли буду, Python, C#, и для веба

Answer (score 2):

Сперва необходимо понять что такое фреймворк. Потому что иногда фреймворки путают с библиотеками. Библиотека это некоторый набор готовых решений для конкретных задач. Например библиотека для работы с растровым изображением. Она потому и библиотека - потому что помогает в работе с растровым изображением (вот какой каламбур). Есть узкоспециализированная задача - есть набор функций (библиотека) для ее решения.

В свою очередь фреймворк помогает с архитектурными задачами - задачами проектирования. Можно 1000 раз использовать разные библиотечные функции, заменять их, переписывать, менять библиотеки. Но что то фундаментальное - архитектура приложения, пишется один раз и поддерживается на всем протяжении жизни приложения. Фреймворк в первую очередь предоставляет каркас - каркас на который надевают все остальное. Вокруг каркаса и организовывается код. Фреймворк позволяет обобщить решение задач, возлагая на конечного пользователя писать более предметно ориентированный код.

Написать свой личный фреймворк это достаточно трудоемкая задача. Написать библиотеку проще. В качестве своего домашнего фреймворка, можно попробовать сделать фреймворк для написания парсеров. Множество людей пишут так или иначе парсеры. Может быть тут можно что то сделать?!

Comment: Я хочу попробовать создать фреймворк графического интерфейса

Comment: @Arteman в начале попробуйте посмотреть что предоставляют другие графические фреймворки. попробуйте выделить минимальный функционал который Вы способны реализовать - без фанатизма. и начинайте предпринимать первые шаги. Но в начале, нужно все таки будет поисследовать.

Comment: @Arteman и хочу Вас предупредить. фреймворк просто так не пишется. необходимы некоторые знания в организации архитектуры. и очень хорошее знание языка для которого вы пишете фреймворк. если Вы не уверены в своих знаниях, лучше отложить данные начинания - чтобы лишний раз себя не огорчать. в качестве практики написать хорошую библиотеку. которая может даже помочь множеству пользователей и стать популярной!

Comment: Хм, спасибо за совет, пожалуй начну с библиотеки, но потом наверное все же попробую